# Issues in joining third Table with OrderBy clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables as

```
First table as=incident
```

[image]

Here I have to select all the values.

```
SECOND table=address
```

[image]

THIRD TABLE as =fire_inc[image]

i used a query as, for `JOIN three tables`.

```
SELECT E . * , D . * ,F.CAUSE_IGN
FROM  `incident_backup` E
LEFT JOIN address D ON E.`INC` = D.`INC` 
LEFT JOIN fire_inc F   ON D.`INC`=F.`INC`
WHERE E.`STATE` =  "AK"
AND SUBSTRING( E.INC_DATE , -4 ) =  "2009" AND D.`INC`>"AK01001105200900000150" 
LIMIT 0 , 10
```

But the query is not working.

I join `two tables` as, `incident and address`

```
SELECT E . * , D . * 
FROM  `incident` E
LEFT JOIN address D ON E.`INC` = D.`INC` 
WHERE E.`STATE` =  "Ak"
AND SUBSTRING( E.INC_DATE , -4 ) =  "2009"
LIMIT 0 , 10
```

When join two it works good.

```
but using ORDERBY

SELECT  E . * , D . * FROM  `incident` E LEFT JOIN address D ON E.`INC` = D.`INC` WHERE E.`STATE` =  'AK' AND SUBSTRING( E.INC_DATE , -4 ) = '2009' and E.INC >"AK01001105200900000150" order by E.INC limit 0,2
```

I not working good.

I have to join all the three tables and I have to select all the fields in all the table.

I need join all the table by INC.

So I need join query for that and I need to use `order by INC`.

In the query getting error as:

```
#2006 - MySQL server has gone away
```

Comment: When you say "not working" do you mean "gives an error" (if so, what is it) or "does not give me the results I expect" (if so, what do you get and what do you expect)

Comment: Hey mate, what do you mean it doesn't work? Doesn't bring data? Did u check if there is any data in the third table related with the others? pls be more specific.

Comment: No need for caps in the title.

Comment: gettin error as,#2006 - MySQL server has gone away  and in have each table have more than 35,000 records.@IngoBürk@dale @medina

Answer (score 0):

Your order by clause uses 'E.INC_KEY', which is not a field in your table.